# How do i get my MAX SQL Select statement to work within my inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've wrote a small inner join that takes column's from two different database tables; WKS_LOG_VIEW and FDE_XML_VIEW. I match them on the ACID/AID and data is returned within the date and machine selected (this works). I have then tried to add a MAX select query that will only put the latest EventTime row in. As i only want one record per EventTime entry. I don't need many EventTime entries just the latest. My query is returning no entries.

```
select 
EXCDS1.dbo.FDE_XML_VIEW.ACID,
EXCDS1.dbo.FDE_XML_VIEW.SID,
EXCDS1.dbo.FDE_XML_VIEW.STAR,
EXCDS1.dbo.FDE_XML_VIEW.ROUTE, 
EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW.AID,
EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW.Sector,
EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW.LocalCoAltIn
EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW.EventTime
from EXCDS1.dbo.FDE_XML_VIEW
inner join
EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW 
on AID = ACID
where
LastUpdateMachine = 'R02'
and
convert (date, EventTime) = '2021-03-11'
and
EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW.EventTime = (SELECT MAX(lv.EventTime) from EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW as lv
where
lv.AID = EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW.AID)
order by ACID, EventTime;
```

I'm very new to SQL so apologies if I'm making obvious mistakes.

Comment: FYI [3+ naming is to be deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/); don't use 3 part (or 4 part as you have hear) naming to refer to your columns, alias your objects and then use those aliases to qualify your code, it'll make it far more succinct and readable. White space and *good* use of linebreaks is also very important. That query is very hard to read and it looks like you have 2 `WHERE`s (which isn't allowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the additional filtering in the query.  The simplest way to solve this uses `row_number()`:

```
select fw.*
from (select f.ACID, f.SID, f.STAR, f.ROUTE, 
             wl.AID, wl.Sector, wl.LocalCoAltIn wl.EventTime,
             row_number() over (partition by wl.AID order by wl.EventTime) as seqnum
      from EXCDS1.dbo.FDE_XML_VIEW f join
           EXCDS.dbo.WKS_LOG_VIEW wl
           on wl.AID = f.ACID
      where LastUpdateMachine = 'R02' and
            convert(date, wl.EventTime) = '2021-03-11'
     ) fw
where seqnum = 1;
order by ACID, EventTime;
```

Notes:

- Use tables aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify *all* column references.  I still have no idea what table `LastUpdateMachine` comes from.
- Your query seems to reference two *views* not two *tables*.  This doesn't matter for your query.  I just want to be sure that you understand the difference between a view and a table.

Comment: Thank you Gordon I will use the aliases and yes they are views I've just checked the database. In the above example the select fw. * knows to pick up the two TABLES as they have aliases of f and wl? I just want to understand the logic.

Comment: @ZZBeard . . . No.  `fw` is the alias on the subquery.

Comment: thanks unfortunately i couldn't get the subquery to work. The results returned blank.

Comment: @zzBeard . . . This query would return no rows only if the subquery returned no rows -- and it is essentially the query in your question.  Does your query return rows?

Comment: This has worked Gordon. My VIEW was emptied and didn't know. Now with data in the system it pulls only one `seqnum`.